# How to enable wobbly windows in the xfce desktop ubuntu 11.10

Tags: compiz, xfce

question pretty much says it all. im running the latest version of xfce desktop. i have compiz manager installed and i had wobbly windows working on unity. is there any way to have this effect on xfce?

Answer (score 1):

I really can't say for sure since I haven't been using Xfce for a while now. But I think you just have to switch WMs i.e. type "compiz --replace" into the command line. Check your settings in CCSM and if it works put a launcher in ~/.config/autostart with said command in it. That should do the trick.